# Spring mvc create indexservlet as root path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I use spring mvc (4.0) and I want to use a servlet to intercept the root mapping ("/") instead of the dispatcherservlet. Spring has a configuration, called "default-servlet-name". The documentation says the following:

`The name of the default Servlet to forward to for static resource requests. The handler will try to auto-detect the container's default Servlet at startup time using a list of known names. If the default Servlet cannot be detected because of using an unknown container or because it has been manually configured, the servlet name must be set explicitly.`

The problem with the above configuration is that the default servlet is called on every request.

Web.xml:

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.main.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

spring-servlet-config.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler  default-servlet-name="index" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.controller"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
              p:prefix="/jsp/"
              p:suffix=".jsp"
              p:requestContextAttribute="rc" />
```

So, with the above configuration, the indexServlet functions as root path. But is called multiple times, because it is the default-handler. If I remove the tag "default-servlet-handler" from the spring config, the page won't load. Any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can have a ending URI pattern to channel the request into two paths. Something like -  *.do

Comment: Thanks for the quik comment. I do not want any extension in my URI.

Comment: You cannot have 2 servlets mapped to the same url-pattern that isn't going to work. What is wrong with the `DispatcherServlet` which calls a `IndexController` instead of a servlet? Also the `default-servlet` is something else as what you think it is, it is the catch-all servlet for requests that cannot be handled by anything else (like serving static resources, global error pages etc). So this is indeed called for each request that cannot be handled or mapped.

Comment: I use an IndexServlet which extends another servlet (from google app engine). This is servlet is used to authenticate the user. This can only be done by using the indexservlet.

Comment: If it can be done with a servlet it can be done with a controller both operate on the request and response. However you cannot have the same url-mapping for 2 different servlets, map your `IndexServlet` to something else and let the `DispatcherServlet` redirect to it for requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that root mapping `/` can only by mapped by the *default servlet* (Java EE sense).

So IMHO, you have only one clean way to meet your requirement : you map spring dispatcher-servlet to `/`, you do not map `IndexServlet` and have spring forward to it for `/` URL.

You could use a `ServletForwardingController` for that :

In web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.main.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In spring-servlet-config.xml:

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
    /=indexForwardingController
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="indexForwardingController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController">
  <property name="servletName"><value>index</value></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This is the solution that I was searching the whole time. I added the configuration and I get an exception ArrayOutOfBound linkedlist. Any suggestions? And is it correct that the indexServlet has no mapping (didnt know you can have one without mapping).

Comment: I did not double check anything, I've updated my post with a simpler  writing of `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` found in my codes. If the problem persists (and you think it comes from here) please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Nah, my fault. I thank you greatly! The exception was thrown because of mine own code. Thanks again!